# Making a query in Web2py and column selection not working

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

I'm working in web2py and I've to make an adHoc user management form, to be more precise I'm making a table with a "role filter". Is important to know that I'm in GAE and the joins must to be done by hand. 
This is my code:

```
auth_user_with_role = db(db.auth_membership.group_id==request.vars.role).select(db.auth_membership.ALL)
auth_user_ids_role_selected=db(db.auth_user.id<1).select(db.auth_user.first_name) #This is a Hack, now I have a ROWS object
for user_role in auth_user_with_role:
    user = db(db.auth_user.id==user_role.user_id).select(db.auth_user.first_name)
    auth_user_ids_role_selected = auth_user_ids_role_selected & user
```

With this code I have a join between the group table and the user table. The problem is that in user variable I have the user with all the columns and not with only the "first_name" column. Is the  projection not working or am I doing something wrong?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

db(db.auth_user.id==user_role.user_id).select(db.auth_user.first_name, projection=True)

Projection=True is necessary to get the projection in Web2Py with Google App Engine.

Why? for backwards compatibility reasons.  prior to projection queries being supported on GAE the default behavior was to return all columns.  when we added projection support i didn't want to break my existing apps that sometimes list fields, but don't have the projection indexes

Credits to: Christian Foster Howes that answer this question in web2py Google Group.